# How to resolve unexpected owner value for volume folder created by Docker Compose for MySQL?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, permissions, dockerfile

Using Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon + Docker Desktop

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml` file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: admin_api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_DATABASE: database_name
      DB_USERNAME: admin_user
      DB_PASSWORD: not_root_password
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    container_name: admin_db
    image: mysql:8
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=not_root_password
      - MYSQL_USER=admin_user
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database_name
    networks:
      - app

networks:
  app:
```

'id' command returns

```
alex@dell:~/Projects/laravel-admin$ id
uid=1000(alex) gid=1000(alex) groups=1000(alex),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(kvm),115(lpadmin),136(sambashare)
```

After success `docker compose up` I have next ->

`db-data` folder created with proper mysql data

'ls -la' command returns:

```
alex@dell:~/Projects/laravel-admin$ ls -la
total 392
drwxr-xr-x 14 alex   alex   4096 May 24 23:12 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 alex   alex   4096 May 23 20:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 alex   alex   4096 May 23 20:12 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 alex   alex   1686 May 16 17:38 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 alex   alex   4096 May 23 20:12 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 alex   alex   1853 May 16 17:38 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 alex   alex 289022 May 23 21:43 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 alex   alex   4096 May 23 23:35 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 alex   alex   4096 May 23 20:12 database
drwxr-xr-x  8 100998 alex   4096 May 24 23:12 db-data <------- here is a strange '100998' value 
-rw-r--r--  1 alex   alex    709 May 24 23:06 docker-compose.yaml
-rw-r--r--  1 alex   alex    351 May 24 21:49 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 alex   alex    258 May 16 17:38 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 alex   alex   1156 May 24 21:14 .env
...
```

Might you tell me please, why Docker creates 'db-data' folder with this strange '100998' owner value and how to fix it?

I already tried to use some 'user' settings like `1000:1000` for `db` service in `docker-compose.yaml`

```
  ...
  db:
    user: "1000:1000" <--- this was added
  ...
```

but in that case `docker compose up` command show errors on `db` service creation step.

```
admin_db   | 2023-05-24 21:20:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
admin_db   | 2023-05-24 21:20:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
admin_db   | mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
admin_db   | 2023-05-24T21:20:06.029099Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
admin_db   | 2023-05-24T21:20:06.029218Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) initializing of server in progress as process 41
admin_db   | 2023-05-24T21:20:06.031268Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010460] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
admin_db   | 2023-05-24T21:20:06.031276Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
admin_db   | 2023-05-24T21:20:06.031309Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
admin_db   | 2023-05-24T21:20:06.031453Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
admin_db exited with code 1
```

And in that case (with `user: 1000:1000` setting) 'db-data' folder is also created and has expected owner

```
alex@dell:~/Projects/laravel-admin$ ls -la                 
total 392
drwxr-xr-x 14 alex alex   4096 May 24 23:20 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 alex alex   4096 May 23 20:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 alex alex   4096 May 23 20:12 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 alex alex   1686 May 16 17:38 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 alex alex   4096 May 23 20:12 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 alex alex   1853 May 16 17:38 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 alex alex 289022 May 23 21:43 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 alex alex   4096 May 23 23:35 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 alex alex   4096 May 23 20:12 database
drwxr-xr-x  2 alex alex   4096 May 24 23:20 db-data <-------- here is
...
```

but this folder is empty (because of docker compose errors -> seems Docker doesn't is not able to write to this folder...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is about the permission. Try to change the ownership of the `db-data` folder on the host machine to match the UID and GID of the MySQL user running inside the container:

- If your UID is 100998 and GID is 1000, then try the following:

  ```
  $sudo chown -R <UID>:<GID> db-data
  $sudo chown -R 100998:1000 db-data
  ```
- After change try the `docker-compose up` again. Docker should now have the permission to write to folder.

Comment: I could do that, but I want to sort out why this folder was created with that specific permission and how to force Docker to create this folder initially with the same permissions that other folders have.